# Set allowed orientations programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, ios8

Hey i try to set my allowed orientations but it won't work.

AppDelegate.m:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
    {
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0){
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
        }else{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
        }

    }
```

In my Info.plist i activated all orientations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app to rotate, you need to set the rotations in every view controllers of your app.

It might be necessary to create a custom class for your `UINavigationController` or `UITabBarController` to make everything rotate as you would think with that kind of code :

```
@implementation CustomTabBarController

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    if(self.viewControllers && self.selectedIndex<self.viewControllers.count)
        return ((UIViewController*)self.viewControllers[self.selectedIndex]).shouldAutorotate;
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if(self.viewControllers && self.selectedIndex<self.viewControllers.count)
        return ((UIViewController*)self.viewControllers[self.selectedIndex]).supportedInterfaceOrientations;
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

@end
```

and

```
@implementation CustomNavigationController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return self.topViewController.shouldAutorotate;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return self.topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}

@end
```

With these two custom classes, you can handle whether your app should rotate or not directly from the `ViewController` itself, so it's kind of convenient like that.

Comment: I dpnt want to rotate. I want to set the allowed oretations. Is it possible to say in the App delegate Wich i support for iOS8 and wich for older versions for the whole app?

Comment: You need to set allowed orientations for every view controllers of your app (or use inheritance to define this only once), but to make it work, you must define it in TabBar and navigationBar if elligible.